# Why are the changes not being reflected in the output?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, backend

I made some changes in the match list in the beginning but at the end when I do `res.json(usr.matches)` the added values are not being reflected in the output.

Why are the changes not being reflected in the output??

```
.post(isUser,(req,res,next) =>{
    var userId  = req.userId;
    var matchId = req.body._id; 
    
    MatchList.findOne({user:userId})
    .then((user) =>{
        var idx = user.likes.indexOf(matchId);
        user.likes.splice(idx,1);
        idx = user.matches.indexOf(matchId);
        if(idx<0) {user.matches.push(matchId);}
        user.save();

        MatchList.findOne({user:matchId})
        .then((matchedUser) =>{
            var matchidx = matchedUser.likes.indexOf(userId);
            matchedUser.likes.splice(matchidx,1);
            if(matchedUser.matches.indexOf(userId)<0)
                matchedUser.matches.push(userId);
            matchedUser.save();
        },(err)=> next(err));


        MatchList.findOne({user:userId})
        .populate('matches')
        .then((usr) =>{
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json')
            res.json(usr.matches);
        },err => next(err));        
    },(err)=> next(err))
    .catch((err)=> next(err))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `db.find({})`, the first thing it takes is the `filter`.
As you can see, you are using `user:userID` , Where user is an object while userId is not an object. So , your output will remain same.

Answer (score 0):

`user.save()` is asynchronous, so it may not execute until after the later `findOne`.

If you need to ensure that the save completes before the findOne executes, either use await or put the subsequent find in a callback passed to save.